# How to resolve ClassNotFoundException in struts2.5?

Tags: struts2-jquery

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [struts2]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExcuteFilter

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration#Struts2.3to2.5migration-StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.